# Setting cookies in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, cookies, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to set cookies using below code

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://mail.google.com");
driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("example@gmail.com");
driver.findElement(By.id("next")).click();
Thread.sleep(3000);
driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys("example999");
driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();
Thread.sleep(3000);
Set<Cookie> cookies=driver.manage().getCookies();
driver.quit();
driver=new FirefoxDriver();
for(Cookie a:cookies){  
    driver.manage().addCookie(a);   
}
driver.get("https://mail.google.com");
```

It is throwing the error as below:

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidCookieDomainException:
You may only set cookies for the current domain
Command duration or timeout: 55 milliseconds
```

Comment: Is your mail.google.com page being redirected?

Comment: No it is throwing error at for loop while adding first cookie

Comment: you instantiate a new Firefox Driver before adding the cookie. It seems, selenium doesn't know the domain for the cookie. Try to remove the second instantiation, or set which domain name you set the cookie

Comment: i tried first navigating to url and then adding cookies.After that i refreshed the page its working fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have something that i done in c# take a look

```
for (int i = 0; i < driver.Manage().Cookies.AllCookies.Count - 1; i++)
{
   System.Net.Cookie ck = new
   System.Net.Cookie(driver.Manage().Cookies.AllCookies[i].Name, driver.Manage().Cookies.AllCookies[i].Value, driver.Manage().Cookies.AllCookies[i].Path, driver.Manage().Cookies.AllCookies[i].Domain);
   //here you can add it to your cookie list.
}
```